# How to click on link - Selenium Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

The below is the HTML that corresponds with the element that I'd like to click on:

```
<TD vAlign=top width="10%"><A onclick=TestCheck() href="javascript:">CheckAll</A></TD>
```

The below code doesn't work for me, please provide the working xpath

```
@FindBy(xpath="//a\[contains(@onclick, 'CheckAll')\]")

WebElement CheckAll;
CheckAll.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xpath="//a\[contains(@onclick, 'CheckAll')\]"
```

Above XPath expression is incorrect because the value of the attribute `onclick` is `TestCheck()`. And not `CheckAll`.

Change your XPath expression as below:

```
xpath="//a[text()='CheckAll']"
```

or this:

```
xpath="//a[contains(@onclick, 'TestCheck()')]"
```

Comment: I tried the above Xpath and getting below error - org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //a[text()='CheckAll')] because of the following error:
[object Error]

Comment: `//a[text()='CheckAll')]` - I see an un-necessary close parenthesis `)`